# How do I get the file name from an Android URI, not just the display name?

Tags: android

so I'm pretty new to Android development. I'm trying to have the user select a song from their SD card or internal storage using a file manager and upload the file to a server. Right now, I'm just trying to access the name of the file that the user selected so that I can use it to access the contents of the file later and upload those contents.

I've looked at other posts concerning this and most of them tell you to query the content resolver and then use the cursor to grab the display name, but that does not always return the display name ([this is mentioned in Google's guide to the SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)). It has not been returning the full file name, just part of it (the title of the song).

Here's my code that starts the intent:

```
Intent chooseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
chooseIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
chooseIntent.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(chooseIntent, SELECT_SONG_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

How I'm getting the display name now:

```
String fileName = null;

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                fileName = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(TAG, "Filename: " + fileName);
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get the full file name rather than just the display name?

Answer (score 0):

You also can use **TITLE** in Cursor as URI parameter to get the full name of file
use below code it

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, null, null, null);
```

Or You can use **DATA** to get Path of the file

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, null, null, null);
```

All You have to do is let the user choose the music and after selecting with the use of **DATA** you have full path of song and with **TITLE** you have full name of file .

Next just upload it.

Comment: Should I be using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` or the actual URI for the file? So far trying the former causes a runtime exception and the latter returns `null` when I try to use **DATA**.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you can do to improve the performance of the query
You are getting all the columns which can be painfully slow. 
You can write code like the one below and then check what field you want to use. You will get all the data for all the audio files installed in the device. You can walk through this code in the debugger to see the data that you need.

{

```
                Uri             objUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                ContentResolver     cr = context.getContentResolver();
                String[] entityColumns =  {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE};

                cursor = cr.query(
                        objUri,
                        entityColumns,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(entityCoumns[0]));
                        String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(entityColumns[1]));
                        String fileTitle =
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(entityColumns[2]));
                    }  while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                }

            }
```